# How to display attached pdf on visualforce page when we are rendering vf page as pdf?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am displaying all attachments in a `Visualforce Page` with `renderAs="pdf"`. It displays the attachment if it is an image but not if it is a pdf. I am using an iframe
to show the pdf attachment but it is not working within a pdf. Is it possible?

Comment: pdf inside pdf ? I don't think you can do that.. What you can do query all the attached pdf get all the blob data and create image with those data.. and display in parent page... I am not sure just assuming .. This can be a way

Comment: You would be better off linking other PDF attachments for reference. Useless in print but it might help depending on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to render a PDF that contains another PDF inside of it. The Salesforce PDF render engine can't render a Blob image. Any images need to be standard formats such as JPG, PNG, GIF, or TIFF images. There might be a few others that are supported as well, but definitely not blobs.

An existing PDF will essentially contain a wrapper around a JPG along with additional information about how to display and print it.